# text overflowed in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[image]

```
Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children:const [
                     Padding(
                      padding:  EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, bottom: 5.0),
                      child: Text(
                        "Data@data",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "title",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'datadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadata',
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
```

Comment: Wrap your Text with Expanded widget.

Answer (score 0):

```
Expanded(
child: Text(
                      'datadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadata',
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    ),)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `column` is inside a `row` widget and inside your `column` you use a long string so for telling `column` how much space should take you need wrap your column with `Expanded`  widget:

```
Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: const [
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, bottom: 5.0),
                      child: Text(
                        "Data@data",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "title",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'datadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadata',
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your **Text** in a **Flexible** to let your element know that it's ok for the Text to be narrower than its intrinsic width. **Expanded** will also work.

Answer (score 0):

you can encapsulate the text with the expanded widget and add the maxlines attribute

```
Expanded(child:
          Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", 
                maxLines:3,
                overflow:TextOverflow.ellipsis ))
```

see the  [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3VvxU4EL51M).